# Windows CE File management API

Tags: windows-mobile

I am just wondering if there is a proper description of the File operations API for Windows CE somewhere on the web. Google was not really helpful so far, I only found simple examples how to read and write files. A proper documentation of the API would be really helpful!

Thanks you

Comment: Note that you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for starters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446567.aspx

I could maybe help you more if you say what you are trying to do, and what device and platform you are using, e.g. are you using compact framework or native, windows mobile professional, standard or classic?

Matt

Comment: Ditto.  If you're looking for information on native APIs, this MSDN site might be good to start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914412.aspx.